# Functions that go to zero at small argument and 1 at large.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I am looking for functions such that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0,$$
and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=1.$$ Some examples are $\exp(-1/y)$, $y/(1+y)$. I am specifically looking for functions that are 'single' in a sense that I don't want something like $1-\exp(-y)$, which contains two terms. Any other potential functions? Special functions would work.

Comment: how about a piecewise constant?

Comment: Some examples: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

Comment: $f(x) = \dfrac{2}{\pi}\arctan x$ works.

Comment: @JohnZHANG a piece wise constant would be rather trivial.

Comment: $f(x)= 1- \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f:(-\frac{1}{2},+\infty)\to \Bbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{2}}+2\right).$$